# Does iOS scan beacon even if bluetooth is off

Tags: ios, bluetooth, ibeacon

I am developing app which interacts with iBeacon. I've seen my app is able to detect iBeacon even if bluetooth is off. I am unable to find any documentation of this behaviour. Can anyone share official verdict/documentation what actually is going on behind the scene?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you tap the Bluetooth icon in Control Center to turn it “off” the icon changes from Blue to Grey, but this does not turn off Bluetooth.  It just disables Bluetooth connections while allowing iBeacon scanning and scanning for other Bluetooth devices to continue.

You can verify this for yourself by turning the Bluetooth icon to the off position in Control Center like this:

[image]

Then drill down into settings to see that the Bluetooth switch is still enabled but below that connections are now disabled.

[image]

You cannot detect if a phone is in this state, but if your app constructs a new `CBCentralManager` when the phone is in this state, iOS will automatically put up a dialog like this:

[image]

If you are not using CBCentralManager, then it doesn't make any difference whether the phone is in this state or not -- you can scan for other devices (iBeacon using CoreLocation or non-iBeacon bluetooth devices using CoreBluetooth) the same way regardless of whether the phone is in this mode.

Comment: Thanks @David this makes sense. Is there any we can determine this from code? that is bluetooth able to detect iBeacon or not ? even if bluetooth is off from control centre.

Comment: See my edited answer.  You can detect iBeacon regardless of whether it is in this state.

Comment: no it does not detect iBeacon when bluetooth is off from settings

Comment: this is expected: "no it does not detect iBeacon when bluetooth is off from settings".  It will only detect when turned off from Control Center, not Settings.

Comment: so is there any way to know or differentiate (programmatically) that bluetooth is off from control centre or from settings as well ?

Comment: You can programmatically tell if Bluetooth is off in settings.  Look for the .poweredOff state here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth/cbcentralmanagerdelegate/1518888-centralmanagerdidupdatestate. But if it is only turned off in control center, you cannot tell programmatically (other than the fact that Bluetooth connections fail)